# "text-decoration: none" is not working with React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I created a NavLink component named CustomNavLink to my React project. Then I needed to add styled component for my CustomNavLink component.I tried "text-decoration: none" and "textdecoration: none" already. But it didn't work. If anyone can help me to solve this it is really appreciated.[This is the screenshot of my CustomNavLink component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTqaS.png)

Comment: shouldn't you write standard CSS in styled components?
Like text-decoration: none instead of textdecoration: none.

Comment: it's `text-decoraction` not `textdecoration`. And same for your margin :)

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
text-decoration: none !important
```